# Win 10 XCOPY partial extension match

Tags: windows-10, command-line, xcopy

There is a file named `README.cppclean` in a directory hierarchy.  I want to copy all `*.cpp` files from the directory tree but not the `*.cppclean` file.

All of the commands below do copy the .cppclean file:

```
xcopy /s /f ..\dirtree\*.cpp
xcopy /s /f "..\dirtree\*.cpp "
xcopy /s /f ..\dirtree\*.cpp.
xcopy /s /f "..\dirtree\*.cpp. "
```

Interestingly, commands below do not copy it:

```
xcopy /s /f ..\dirtree\*.c
xcopy /s /f ..\dirtree\*.cp
xcopy /s /f ..\dirtree\*.cppc
xcopy /s /f ..\dirtree\*.cppcl
xcopy /s /f ..\dirtree\*.cppcle
xcopy /s /f ..\dirtree\*.cppclea
```

Of course

```
xcopy /s /f ..\dirtree\*.cppclean
```

also copies the .cppclean file.

QUESTION: How to copy all `*.cpp` (but not `*.cppclean`) files using `XCOPY`?  (I do not want to explicitly exclude the .cppclean file because, in general case, there could be other files like it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you clarified in a comment that you prefer not to explicitly exclude some unwanted file extension which you wish not be copied and would prefer a method that only copies the files with the extension as you specify, I'll provide you with a detailed solution below.

> **Essentially this will . . .**
>
> - Use a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) using `TOKENS=*`and the [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command with the `/s` and `/b`
>     switches to traverse the directories with the `.cpp` files recursively
>     that will be copied.
> - From there use conditional [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic to verify with batch variable substitutions that the file extension is
>     indeed only `.cpp` and if that is true then it will copy only those
>     files per each iteration of the loop
> - The final `XCOPY` command will be `XCOPY /s /f "%Src%\*%~nxF" "%Dst%` so it still gets the explicit file names from the `DIR` command but with the asterisk wildcard in front of it though—the conditional logic still ensures no other files than just .CPP named files are copied

### Command Line

**Note:** *Set the source (`Src=`) and destination (`Dst=`) variable values for your need*

```
SET Src=C:\Users\User\Desktop\CPP
SET Dst=C:\CPP2
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %F IN ('dir /s /b "%Src%\*.cpp"') DO IF %~xF==.cpp ECHO F | XCOPY /s /f "%Src%\*%~nxF" "%Dst%\"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

  - **`FOR /?`**

    > ```
    >     tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
    >                       be passed to the for body for each iteration.
    >                       This will cause additional variable names to
    >                       be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
    >                       specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
    >                       the last character in the tokens= string is an
    >                       asterisk, then an additional variable is
    >                       allocated and receives the remaining text on
    >                       the line after the last token parsed.
    > ```
    >
    > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
    >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
    >
    > ```
    > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    > ```
- [DIR](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I believe I did mention not wanting to "explicitly exclude" some files in the original question (and later again in the comment).

I like your proposal because it does not require any "unwanted file exclusion".  However, I do find one problem with it.  Directory structure from which files are copied is not replicated.  All files end up in the same destination directory.  (NB using %~pF as part of the destination specification does not help since dir /s lists the entire path of each file all the way from the drive letter.  Some more manipulation is required...)

Comment: @PetrVepřek Good point, I missed that as my small test was with files in separate subfolders with the same file names so I did not notice since all structures and files were in place when I tested. I believe I figured out a way that will work here: https://justpaste.it/1fu3i but I don't want to edit my answer until I confirm it's a solution that works 100% for you. I just copied the command line logic to that link that I used but I do set a destination and source path explicitly. Essentially appending a wildcard `*` to `%~nxF` and putting the `%Src%\` in front of that gets the expected result.

Comment: So the final `XCOPY` command looks something like `XCOPY /s /f "%Src%\*%~nxF" "%Dst%` so it still gets the explicit name with the asterisks wildcard in front of it though, and the conditional logic will still ensure no other files than just `.CPP` named files are copied. I hope this helps you and if so I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @PetrVepřek I have another idea if that'll not suffice but just curious if the quick adjusted solution would suffice or not but I have one other thing I will test if that does not help or causes issue based on duplicate or similar matching file names.

Comment: Good timing!  :-)  I was off the grid for a few days and just got back, saw your comment, and was in fact giving it a go when your follow up comment came.  In my tiny test, your proposal worked as expected.  Nice!  But remember, I did not test it thoroughly yet.

Comment: @PetrVepřek Ah.... No worries, I'm glad to hear from you regardless. Take your time and be thorough with it for sure. Hit me back once you figure out either way and I'll wait to hear back on your result and outcome.

Comment: So far your solution works for me.  If you update your answer, I will accept it.  (I wish there was a way to "fix / work-around" the fact that xcopy does not match the source extension as expected i.e. *.cpp copies *.cpp and *.cppclean files while *.cp does not copy either.  Fixing it in one go would be faster than iterating...  However, iterating is better than unexpected results. :-)

Comment: @PetrVepřek I've updated my answer as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/EXCLUDE:` argument.
`/EXCLUDE expects a file containing a list of excluded files.

So create a a file called "excludedfileslist.txt" containing:

> .cppclean

Then use a command like this:

> xcopy /s /f /exclude:excludedfileslist.txt ..\dirtree\cpp

Comment: Yes, this works, and thanks.  However, I would like xcopy to match the exact extension (cpp in this case).  So I am hoping for something more general (than explicitly excluding some files).  That's why I tried to tack on a space after the extension (using quotes) but this must get stripped and does not help.

PS: Would .cppclean also exclude .cppclean.cpp?  It seems it would...